# Bayesian biostatistics book

Tags: bayesian, references, biostatistics

I am looking for a good book on biostatistics from a Bayesian point of view. I am going to be starting some research in oncology and so books geared towards that would be great, but also just a general book on biostats is even better.

Comment: At this point in my career, I'm starting to feel like "Biostatistics" can mean two very distinct areas: traditional biostatistics and analysis of sequencing data. Unfortunately, preparing for one of those areas gives you just about 0 preparation for the other area.

Answer (score 1):

There are two chapters that you might find interesting in a book called: **Bayesian Nonparametrics** by Hjort  et al. - ISBN: 978-1107012271

The two chapters are called:

1. Nonparametric Bayes applications to biostatistics by Dunson
2. More nonparametric Bayseian models for biostatistics by Muller et al.

There is also a Springer book, **Nonparametric Bayesian Inference in Biostatistics** by Mitra - ISBN: 9783319195179

I found a fairly good list of papers, many by Muller, Mitra and colleagues:
https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/pmueller/paper.html

Answer (score 1):

there are a few people who are strong proponents of the bayesian approach, are well known and have good books out there. Eg from north america you have Don Berry and from Europe you have david spiegelhater:

[Statistics: A Bayesian Perspective](https://www.amazon.ca/Statistics-Bayesian-Perspective-Donald-Berry/dp/0534234720)

[Bayesian Approaches to Clinical Trials and Health-Care Evaluation](https://www.amazon.ca/Bayesian-Approaches-Clinical-Health-Care-Evaluation/dp/0471499757/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1514265112&sr=8-5&keywords=david%20spiegelhalter)

[The BUGS Book: A Practical Introduction to Bayesian Analysis](https://www.amazon.ca/BUGS-Book-Practical-Introduction-Bayesian/dp/1584888490/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1514265112&sr=8-3&keywords=david%20spiegelhalter)

for a general book geared towards oncology ... i believe Piantodosi is in cancer research and he has a great book:

[Clinical Trials: A Methodologic Perspective](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01K3KFWMM)

[Steven Piantadosi, MD, PhD](http://bio.csmc.edu/view/15122/Steven-Piantadosi.aspx)

Comment: Good answer, I don't know whether the Piatadosi book covers this, but I guess with current trends towards things like basket trials etc., it may be worthwhile to read a review paper on that (not sure there's a book, yet). There must be a book covering things like the Bayesian (Oncology) dose escalation trials that have mostly replaced the 3+3 design, but again, not sure the books above cover that.